# Dead lock on table's primary key when running multiple of the same query

Tags: sql-server, database-deadlocks

I have a query that is causing deadlocks on the primary key of a table. The query can run from multiple different code paths. New DB connections are created each time a query needs to be run, so this is not a connection reuse issue, as far as I can tell.

The query in question is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[upd_task]       @taskid               INTEGER
      , @state                INTEGER
      , @args                 NVARCHAR( max )
      , @retries              INTEGER
      , @started              bit
      , @finished             bit
      , @username             NVARCHAR( 50 )    AS  BEGIN   BEGIN TRAN
      UPDATE task WITH (updlock) SET
          [state]        = @state
        , args           = @args
        , retries        = @retries
        , started   = @started
        , finished      = @finished
        , modifier      = @username
        , modified     = GETDATE()
      WHERE
        task.task_id   = @taskid    COMMIT  END
```

The table is defined as

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[task](
    [task_id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [job_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [car_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [uuid] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [user_priority] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [args] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [state] [int] NOT NULL,
    [started] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [finished] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [failed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [error_msg] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [retries] [int] NULL,
    [exec_time] [datetime] NULL,
    [created] [datetime] NULL,
    [creator] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [modified] [datetime] NULL,
    [modifier] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_task_id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [task_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[task] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [user_priority]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[task] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [state]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[task] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [started]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[task] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [finished]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[task] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [failed]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[task] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [retries]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[task]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_task_car] FOREIGN KEY([car_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[car] ([car_id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[task] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_task_car]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[task]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_task_job] FOREIGN KEY([job_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[job] ([job_id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[task] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_task_job]
GO
```

The dead lock graph, shown below, has two instances of the same query running [upd_task.e
[image]

Comment: Why are you specifying the lock type in your update statement? In general query hints like this should be avoided unless your testing has proven they are actually required. And why bother with an explicit transaction around a single update statement? You already have an implicit transaction happening.

Comment: @SeanLange those have all been added in the last day or two to try and resolve this locking issue. They have had no effect thus far and, as you pointed out, should be removed.